# Create dynamic / data driven pages in wordpress

Tags: plugins, customization

I am driven to create dynamic, data driven, SEO optimised pages in wordpress without having to manually create lots of pages.

For example if I know that I sell all my cars in Red, Blue, Green and White then I want to add just;

"Ford Focus"

And I want to have pages available and in the site map for;

https://mywebsite/Ford-Focus

https://mywebsite/Ford-Focus/Red

https://mywebsite/Ford-Focus/Blue

https://mywebsite/Ford-Focus/Green

https://mywebsite/Ford-Focus/White

What is the best way to achieve?

Is there a plug in for this?

I am quite new to wordpress though I have done some child themes and php scripting.

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially many ways to achieve what you want to do. My approach would be to use WooCommerce and then define 'Ford Focus' as a product. I then would configure the product to offer the various different colors and/or any other features.

This approach would not create 5 pages on  the sitemap. It would create a single product for Ford Focus, and this should be sufficient for the SEO, because you would use rich-snippets to define the individual products and features and Google recognizes and uses rich snippets as part of the ranking.

Also, while optimization for Google is important, the creation of 5 separate would not lead to a good user experience and user experience is the key to success. A single dynamic page with all the configuration options (color, engine capacity, etc.) would in my opinion be the way to go. You can achieve this using the standard (and often free) features in WooCommerce (or Easy Cart, or Cart Press etc.) plugins.

Comment: Clinton thanks for the suggestion.  I really don't want to use WooCommerce though since the site is not about selling a product in that way (the ford focus example was just that, not really selling cars).  But again thanks, good idea but probably not one I'll follow though

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you want to create pages and then import these directly into Wordpress with the SEO in place. If so have a look at wp-all-import. I have used this and it is excellent for importing Excel, XML and other formats.